# Angular 8 + Rxjs avoid if tree chaining

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

I'm new to angular and Rxjs world. I'm making my uno game and i have a working code, however i am not satisfied with the look of it. Is there any better way to handle promises, when they are resolved, than chaining IF statements? To be precise i am using bootstrap modals, and i need to resolve what's returned from it.
To clarify, this is my code:

```
if (something) {
        this._modalService.open(SomeComponent).result.then(pickedColor => {
        if (something) {
          const playerModal = this._modalService.open(SomeComponent);
          playerModal.result.then((playerId: string) => {
            if (something) {
              this._modalService.open(SomeComponent).result.then((duelNumbers: number[]) => {
                this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, playerId, null, duelNumbers);
                return;
              });
            } else if (something) {
              const modalRef = this._modalService.open(SomeComponent);
              modalRef.result.then((charityCardsIds: string[]) => {
                this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, playerId, null, null, charityCardsIds);
                return;
              });
            } else {
              this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, playerId);
              return;
            }
          });
        } else if (something) {
          const digModal = this._modalService.open(SomeComponent);
          digModal.result.then((cardToDigId: string) => {
            this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, null, cardToDigId);
            return;
          });
        } else if (something) {
          this._modalService.open(SomeComponent, { backdrop: 'static' }).result.then(blackjackNumber => {
            this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, null, null, null, null, blackjackNumber);
            return;
          });
        } else if (something) {
          this._modalService.open(SomeComponent).result.then(numbersToDiscard => {
            this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor, null, null, null, null, 0, numbersToDiscard);
            return;
          });
        } else {
          this._hubService.playCard(card.id, pickedColor);
          return;
        }
      });
    } else if (something) {
      this._hubService.playCard(card.id);
      return;
    }`
```

Is there any way to remove this "if chains"? Like can i have a list of promises, and just add to it, and in the end say if everything resolved, just _hubService.playcard(all the possible params - 7 of them)?

Comment: You can pass an array of Promises to `Promise.all()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @WillAlexander how exactly would you apply it to my code? i don't know the exact number of promises that need to be resolved. It's depending on the IF statements, so once i call _hubService.playCard(X,X,X,X,X,X) how do i know which X is resolved? (some of them must resolve null i guess?)

Comment: `Promise.all` only resolves if all of its internal Promises resolve. It may be better to use Observables in your case rather than Promises. You'd still need a bunch of 'if's (because it seems like that's just the logic of your program), but you could instead pass different Observables down the chain depending on the outcomes of your 'if's, and catch the response in the next operator.

Comment: @WillAlexander That sounds about right, i just wanna get rid of the "if tree chain". Can you give me an example of how this would look? Maybe on stackblitz if you will have time. Thanks!

Comment: You know what? I started trying to code it and it got ugly fast. Perhaps simply breaking down your code into separate functions would be the best approach. Have one function for each `modalService.stuff.then()` with the call to `playCard`. That way it tidies this section up and allows you to add semantic names, making the logic easier to follow.